# there is environment variable set in remote host. $home=/apps/tesco/app/. i want to ssh to that host and want to go cd $home

Tags: shell

I am able to ssh into the host but I am not able to go to the location of the environment variable that I set at a remote host.

Remote host env variable:

```
$HOME=/apps/tesco/app/
```

After doing ssh to the remote host
when I give 
`cd $HOME` in my script.

It's not going to the location `/apps/tesco/app/`

Summary:
I want to go to the location of the environment variable that is set at a remote host. how to call in a shell script.

```
ssh ${user}@${host[$nn]} -qtt -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null "sudo su - ${sid[$nn]}adm  <<EOF
cd $HOME   ------it should go /apps/tesco/app/...But its not going
ls -ltr
```

it should go to the location that is set in environment variable and list down the file
 under location `/apps/tesco/app/`.

Comment: I don't see anything that sets `$HOME` in the code you posted.  Are you perhaps setting it outside of the `su -` command?

Comment: its already set in the remote machine. I want to use that location in remote host . Inshort after ssh cd $HOME will let me to get into /apps/tesco/app/. and after that i can access the file in that location.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about *how* it's set "in the remote machine".  Do you mean that it's `${user}`'s home directory?  That doesn't mean very much, as the `su -` will override that, and `$HOME` will then be `root`'s home directory.  You'll want to set it within the process run by `su`.  (And really, you ought to set up suitable keys so you can directly ssh as `root` for this command, rather than having to immediately `su`).

Answer (score 0):

You've probably created your `$HOME` variable in `.bashrc` file which is not executed/sourced when you `ssh` into a machine. Add the following in your `.bash_profile` file instead. It gets sourced when you ssh.

```
export $HOME=/apps/tesco/app/
```

Comment: its already set in the remote host. I want to use that location in remote host . Inshort after ssh.....if i give  cd $HOME, it will let me to get into /apps/tesco/app/ and after that i can access the file in that location.